# AngularJS - ngOptions in a select - How to validate before changing the model?

Tags: angularjs

Im using AngularJS. I have a `select` with several options. To work with this options Im using `ngOptions` and `ng-model`. When the value in the select changed, I do a `PUT operation`. If it successes then this selection should be transmitted to the model. In case of failed, the model should not get this new selection.

```
<select class="form-control" ng-change="updateSelection(object)" 
 ng-model="object.status" ng-options="status as label for (label, status) in CONSTANTS">
</select>
```

My issue is that due to `ng-model` and two-way binding, whenever I do a change the new selection is transmitted to the model without any validation. Is there any way to do some validation before updating the model?

Comment: remove ng-model and assign correct value to your model in updateSelection function

Comment: @NarekMamikonyan, `ng-options` would not work without `ng-model`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just use one variable for selection (that is assigned to `ng-model`), and one variable for the final value:

```
<select ng-change="updateSelection(object, selection)" 
        ng-model="selection" 
        ng-options="status as label for (label, status) in CONSTANTS">
</select>
```

And in the controller:

```
$scope.updateSelection = function(object, selection){
  $http.put(url, selection)
    .then(function(data){
       object.status = selection;
    })
    .catch(function(){
       selection = null;
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

For a more "proper" approach, you could use an async validator. This can be attached to any input with `ng-model`.

Here's an example of fake validator with `$timeout`:

```
app.directive("fakeValidator", function($timeout, $q){
  return {
    require: "ngModel",
    scope: {
      fakeValidator: "="
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel){
      ngModel.$asyncValidators.fake = function(modelValue, viewValue){

        // don't invalidate empty values
        if (!viewValue) {
          return $q.when(true);
        }

        return $timeout(function(){
          // invalidate if the attribute value was false
          return scope.fakeValidator ? true : $q.reject(); 
        }, 1000)
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Invalid values would not propagate to the model:

```
<select ng-model="object.status" fake-validator="false" 
        ng-options="status as label for (label, status) in CONSTANTS">
</select>
```

[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/FtjB38lDhw54TYgbE4yM?p=preview)

Comment: in this way, your model selection is keeping a copy of object.status (as a way to initialize the select correctly). I know that angularjs works a lot with copies (like in this example)... But if my UI is a table with 50 rows and each row has a select... That would be a lot of duplicate values! Any other way to validate data before the model acquires the selected value?

Comment: With Angular, the concern is not about memory but the amount of $watched properties. One way or the other there will be a copy somewhere. But, probably the "clean" way would be to implement an async validator - I have updated the question